# How to run Scala FreeSpec tests with console using Maven?

Tags: scala, maven, testing

I would like to type something like

```
mvn test
```

to run all the tests(FreeSpec tests) I have in the library.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Maven actually runs test with `mvn test` command, but only those whose names end with "Test". I guess this mask is configurable too.